# Get categories and descriptions from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to pull all of the categories associated with a custom post type within a loop, but I'm not sure how to get it so automatically pulls all of the categories automatically from the associated post type?

My reason is that if a user wants to add/remove a category from the custom post type, I don't want to have to edit the template file to manually add or remove the category name.

I currently have this:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'rentals');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<div class="fg12 rentals">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="info">
  <?php category_description(); ?>
  <a class="button" href="<?php the_field('rental_item_link') ?>">
    Learn More &rarr;
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And I know if I add `'category_name' => 'cat-slug1, cat-slug2, etc...'` it will pull those specific categories, but I'm trying to avoid doing that manually in case someone wants to add or remove a specific category.

I'm also trying to get the category description as well, but I'm not sure if I am pulling that correctly either.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You are using the categories tag and custom-taxonomy tag. Are you categories built in categories or taxonomies that you registered through `register_taxonomy`

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

I had to create a custom taxonomy and assign it to my custom post type.

Once I did that, I has to attrbute all of the custom posts to the new custom taxonomy (there's a plugin that I found that does it quickly).

then I just did a `foreach` loop with `get_categoeries`.

```
<?php $args = array('type' => 'rentals', 'taxonomy' => 'rental-categories');
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo'
   <div class="fg12 rentals">
   <h2> '. $category->name . '</h2>
  <div class="info">
  <p>'. $category->description . '</p>
     <a class="button" href="#">
       Learn More &rarr;
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for a way to create an archive of categories (with descriptions) for users to click and go to a specific category archive. This works great.